C# .NET 4.8 Material Design SmartHint display bug
We've been using materialDesign for wpf for a while now but since the last update those TextBox:
enter image description here
That looks like this in our XML:
<TextBox
Grid.Row="1"
Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignOutlinedTextBox}"
GotFocus="SizeTextBox_GotFocus" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
PreviewKeyDown="TextBox_PreviewKeyDown"
materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="{x:Static p:Resources.Height}"
FontSize="25" Height="60" Padding="10" Margin="20"
materialDesign:TextFieldAssist.SuffixText="{Binding Unit, Converter={StaticResource UnitAbbreviation}}"
BorderBrush="{StaticResource PrimaryColorBrush}"
materialDesign:HintAssist.Background="{StaticResource ThirdColorBrush}"
materialDesign:ValidationAssist.Background="{StaticResource ThirdColorBrush}">

    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SelectedParameter.Height" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <utility:NumericValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>

have those weird black sidebars.
I tried to modify each and everyone props you can access through materialDesign:HintAssist but nothing did the trick.
I also tried to use this to modify the hint :
<TextBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type materialDesign:SmartHint}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="red"/>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Resources>

It seems I can modify some stuff, mostly props accessible through HintAssist, but setting some other properties doesn't change a thing, margin and padding do nothing for example.

What do you mean using materialDesign ? Material Design is a Google style guide. You're using some library that implements this. Which library is it? Searching for materialdesign in NuGet returns 111 results

We use this :
http://materialdesigninxaml.net/
sorry i was rude by not saying hello btw
